# Returning JSON - C# .NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I have a document containing valid JSON content. It's saved on my machine as filename.json

I have a web page using that uses and ajax post to call a method that will return a json object.

> ** Note, I probably dont need to Post,  I'm not actually using the SearchObject or the Id I'm passing, this was cut an past from another
>    page, just trying to get it to work before cleaning it up.

The method my ajax is calling:

```
        [WebMethod]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public JsonResult GetJson(SearchObject model)
        {

            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\mroberts\Desktop\filename.json");
            return Json(text);
        }
```

This is working, it returns data in the following format:

```
 [{"NAME":"xxx  xxxx",
   "DIRECT PHONE":"(xxx) xxx-xxxx",
   "EMAIL":"xxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com",
   "JOB TITLE":"xxxxxx",
   "DEPARTMENT":"xxxxxx"}]
```

My Jquery/Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
        $("a#BigButton").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var a = $(this).attr("id");

            var data = {
                Id: a
            }
            $.ajax({
                //url: "../Controllers/Home/GetTier",
                url: "/Home/GetJson",
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                context: this,
                error: function () { },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    var loop = $(response).size();
                    for (var i = 0; i < loop + 1; i++) {
                        console.log(response);

                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

However, when I return this, I am logging it to my console, and am getting an error: **Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:** my json result....

Im not sure why this is invalid. I validated I've reviewed my result, and used online validation to verify the structure of my json, and it appears to be fine.

Am I overlooking something?

Is it the "return Json" that is breaking things?

Comment: Where are you getting the error? But if you string is *already* JSON, then you don't need to turn it into JSON.

Comment: Can I just return it as a string? Or should I create a list first, and return a list?

Comment: I'm getting the error in my console when I log the response.

Comment: you mean when you console.log the response in your browser? try `console.log("%o", response);`

Comment: @Mark JSON is a plain text format, just like HTML. If your file is JSON, you don't need to turn it into JSON *again*, that's just like HTML-encoding and HTML file would lead to broken output.

Comment: What is `$(response)` supposed to do here?

Comment: @BrettCaswell , the %o, worked, what did that do exactly?

Comment: it depends on your browser, but `%o` will log an object explicitly. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api .. it would seem that `console.log(response)` is attempting to parse your `response`.

Comment: Try `$.each(response, function(i, item) { console.log(item); });` in your success callback.

Comment: @MattBurland, the problem / solution may be related, but it certainly isn't a duplicate..

Comment: @BrettCaswell It is a duplicated. `Json(text)` turns `text` into JSON. it does not care whether `text` already contains JSON, it will simply encode it *again*. Simply returning the raw file content is one way to solve this. (A better way might be to to a parse-and-encode pass on the server to rule out the possibility that the client ever receives broken JSON, even if the file itself became invalid)

Comment: @Tomalak, to draw you a comparison: questions are like exceptions.. they are raised.. this question inherits the other one, and they have the same set of solutions/handling (mostly).. but people are more likely to raise THIS question. based on these flags, yall seem to think `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` is `System.Data.Common.DbException`

Comment: @Mark Given your lack of further comments I take it that the duplicate thread has in fact helped you?